# Расстояние между cardView

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, cardview

[image]

Не могу понять, почему между элементами такое большое расстояние. Вроде бы всё делаю согласно руководствам из Интернета.

Код карточки:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="310dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/card_img"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

код активити

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

взято [отсюда](http://androiddocs.ru/cardview-primer-ispolzovaniya/)

Comment: а в коде вы ничего с view-ми не делаете?

Comment: Это у вас в графическом редакторе студии такое? На девайсе пробовали? Там всё нормально должно быть.

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

действительно, ступил. свитер-про был прав. выставил android:layout_height="wrap_content" и все встало как надо